# To clone "aosp-master-throttled-copped" branch in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I am working on to bring-up cuttlefish in ARM processor. Following this (https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/cuttlefish/) link.

In the document they have mentioned "For ARM, use branch aosp-master-throttled-copped and device target `aosp_cf_arm64_only_phone-userdebug` ".

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b aosp-master-throttled-copped`

```
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/aosp-master-throttled-copped

fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/aosp-master-throttled-copped

fatal: cannot obtain manifest https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

It seems to aosp-master-throttled-copped branch is not available. How could we get the this branch source code.

Comment: that branch is not available for public source code, perhaps. Only the CI build artifacts are available for download https://ci.android.com/builds/branches/aosp-master-throttled-copped/grid?legacy=1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen this link but they are providing prebuilt binaries. I am looking for the source code. Do you have any idea to download this branch code?